# Need to right align decimal number in ol list

Tags: html, css

I have a standard `ol` list:

```
1. One
2. Two
10. Ten
```

Is there any way to get the decimal number to right align so that it looks like this:

```
 1. One
 2. Two
10. Ten
```

**EDIT**: Screenshot. Top is Typekt (Proxima Nova) font-weight normal. Bottom is sans-serif.

Only relevant style is: `ol { list-style-position: inside; }`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't the item numbers right-aligned by default? At least they are in IE and Firefox:

```
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li value="10">Ten</li>
</ol>
```

**UPDATE:** The problem is that (1) `list-style-position` is set to `inside`, so the item number appears as part of the item content instead of in the left margin, and (2) you're using a font with variable-width digits.

Removing `list-style-position: inside` would fix the problem. What's the reason that you added it? If a footnote is so long that it wraps, how do you want subsequent lines to be indented?

Comment: I'm using a font from Typekit. Just turned it off and they do line up at the decimal point. Are there any built in ways to handle differences in typefaces?

Comment: It surprises me that changing the font would also change the alignment. Perhaps you can post your CSS and a screenshot?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Thanks, that was the problem with getting the decimal points to line up. If I set it to `outside` the decimal points do line up correctly but because of the variable-width font, the numbers looked weird. I think that's why it was set to `inside` in the first place. Looks like I'll just use a different font for footnotes.